# Which sound format to use? iOS Notifications

Tags: ios, iphone, audio, avaudioplayer

I have 12 custom sound notifications. They are currently .wav and are 500kb per sound which I think is pretty big. Which format/codec should I use and how do I convert it? I'm trying to get the file size as small as possible but without losing any quality. This sound notifications are for an iPhone app. I tried converting it to caf with "afconvert -d LEI16 -f 'caff'" but that made the sound file even bigger.

Thanks

Comment: 500kb isn't that big, but it's not always the format, it's the length. If your sound is > ~10sec it's going to naturally be a bigger size. Compression does play a role as well however

Answer (score 3):

You should use `.aiff` format for the notifications. You can convert files to `.aiff` format online. Just check out this link:
http://audio.online-convert.com/convert-to-aiff

The size of file in `.aiff` format is around 100kb.